# Setting a background image while loading an Android app

Tags: android

How do I add a background to my android app at loading time?
Now it shows white page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
  Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        try {
           int waited = 0;
           while (waited < 1000) {
              sleep(100);
              waited += 100;
           }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
           // do nothing
        } finally {

           Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,Party_tablayout.class);

           startActivity(i);
           finish();
        }
     }
  };
  splashThread.start();
 }
}
```

Hope this helps you..:-)

Answer (score 1):

thanks dude, it really works. but you can also use a different piece of code in try block.
like this :

```
Thread th = new Thread(){
  public void run(){
    try {
      long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
      while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= current + 6000){
        //do nothing.
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      final Intent intent = new Intent(NeredeyimBenActivity.this, AnaSayfa.class);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
};
th.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a launcher activity, where you only show your bg image and maybe a progress bar or something. 
Do everything that takes time in there. Like preloading a bunch of bitmaps, fetch stuff from the internet, whatever is done that takes your app that long to load.
Once this is done call your main activity via an intent.